# Please let me know the usage is correct or not 'one more than another by 10'

Tags: word-usage

Please let me know whether the following usage is correct.

one is more than another by 10 percent.

Comment: It looks grammatically sound, though the first word could do with a capital letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"One is more than another by 10 percent." is, as a standalone sentence, grammatically incorrect. What is necessary is an *attribute* which is being measured. So the following would both make sense:

> This necklace is more **expensive** than that one by 10 percent
>
> This boy is **taller** than that one by 10 percent

Both of these mean that if the measured attribute is 100 for the first item, the second item has a value of 110 for that attribute.